# setState to undefined, then on next rendering setState to a value, the render content is incorrect

Tags: reactjs

Code sample is here:
https://codepen.io/zeroarst/pen/qBLYXzv

The flow is:

1. App renders. Because `value === undefined`, then `setState(1)` is called, `AddingUp` is not rendered.
2. App renders, with value updated to *1*. `AddingUp` is rendered, shows value *11* (AddingUp its initial `useRef` value *10* plus passing value 1* in prop.
3. *Press clear* button, `setState(undefined)` is called.
4. App renders with value updated to undefined. Because `value === undefined`, `setState(1)` is called, return view with `AddingUp` not rendered (because *value is undefined*), hence its `useRef` value should be gone.
5. (Expect) App renders with value updated to *1*, return view with `AddingUp` is rendered, initial value is *10*, hence it should show *11*.

But actually, it just adding up. The problem is that at *4*, `AddingUp` is still there when value in App is *undefined*.

And I found if I use

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  setValue(1)
}, 0)
```

It works....

Comment: `AddingUp` is not unmounted when you set `undefined` in the state on button click. This is because before the JSX content is rendered (with `value` as `undefined`, you update it to 1. As a result, `AddingUp` is not unmounted. With `setTimeout`, the `AddingUp` component will be unmounted. As a result, its `useRef` value will be reset.

Comment: You **mustn't** update state inside *conditionals* ! It's a very bad practice that can get your application broken...

Comment: as other said, dont set state conditionaly. instead, add it to useEffect

Comment: @Lith is right, useEffect would be the best approach.

Comment: example: https://codepen.io/Edvinas-Baranauskas/pen/jOXxoeK?editors=1111